# Python decorator for class

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

I try do this:

```
import unittest

def decorator(cls):
    class Decorator(cls):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(Decorator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    return Decorator

@decorator
class myClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(myClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.test = 'test'

    def test_test(self):
        pass


myClass().run()
```

But I get recursion in `MyClass.__init__`. Are there any ways to avoid this?

Comment: Hint to OP: If you paste reduced code here, please make sure it really still shows the problem you are about to solve.  In this case just paste the posted code into an interactive Python and try it out.

Comment: I've updated my code to problem version.

Comment: What is that `decorator` supposed to be doing in its role as a "class decorator"...

Comment: Why aren't you using `setUp` instead of overriding `__init__`?

Comment: It adds additional steps to `setUp()` method for different `unittest.TestCase` subclasses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use `super(myClass, self)` within a decorated class in this way.

`myClass` is looked up as a global, and the global `myClass` is *rebound* to `Decorator`, so you are telling Python to look in the class MRO for `__init__` starting from `Decorator` which is `myClass`, which calls `super(myClass, self).__init__()`, looking up `myClass` as a global, which is bound to `Decorator`, etc.

The easiest work-around is to not use `super()` here:

```
@decorator
class myClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        unittest.TestCase.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.test = 'test'
```

This is one of the reasons why in Python 3 the argument-less version of `super()` was introduced, giving methods a `__class__` cell instead.

You *could* jump through some (very tricky) hoops to re-compile the `myClass.__init__()`  method to give it a `myClass` closure bound to the original undecorated class object instead, but for a unittest, I would not bother.